# docker: Only execute command in when container is running

Tags: docker

I want to create a backup of a mount volume in my docker container.
This is the command in my dockerfile:

```
RUN tar -cvpzf test.tar -C /test/ .
```

But the problem is that it can only be executed after the mount of my volume. (because my volume will be mounted to `/test/`

So this command needs to be executed after starting the docker container and not when I'm creating the image. How do I have to perform this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't mount volumes in a Dockerfile, because images are meant to be portable.  What you would like to do is more of a task that could be the sole job of a container (using `docker run`) or a command that you would execute against a running container (using `docker exec`).

Comment: Hi threeve, I know that's not possible. So I want to execute a command only after my container started up (not when creating the image). Because than the volume is mounted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your container is running, assuming the container has `tar`, you can do exactly what you want with:

```
docker exec nameofcontainer [options] tar -cvpzf test.tar -C /test/ .
```

You can get the names of running containers using `docker ps`.  For options, you may want to use `-ti` so that you can see the output.

You could also build the container with a custom `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` which will both start whatever the primary job of the container is going to be and run your backup script, as well as any other tasks that need performing.

The [official mysql container](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/f7a67d7634a68d319988ad6f99729bfeaa84ceb2/5.7/Dockerfile) does something like this, with the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script.

Comment: That's the way I was doing this. But I want to have it automated from container startup.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option.  See if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me further